# Replace character if not preceded nor followed by same character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace non-consecutive single quotes in a string with two consecutive quotes.

**Examples (in/out)**

- `"abc'def"` --> `"abc''def"`
- `"abc''de'f"` --> `"abc''de''f"`
- etc.

Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds, so the following regular expression I'd use with Java (well, more or less) will **not** compile:

```
myString.replace(/(?<!)'(?!'))/g, "''");
```

I have looked around SO and some answers advise using a non-capturing group containing a custom character class negating the character that would otherwise be in the negative lookbehind:

```
myString.replace(/(?:[^'])'(?!'))/g, "''");
```

However, that will not do either: it will successfully not replace the two consecutive single quotes, but in the `"abc''de'f"` example, it will "eat" the `f` when replacing the next single quote with two consecutive single quotes, ending up in:

`"abc''de''gh"` (see it's missing the `f`!)

**Questions**

- Is there a suitable regex-based solution for this problem?
- If not, should I just go with a barbaric iteration and indexing of all the input string's characters and painfully build another string from it (please no)?

Comment: How would you handle triple quotes? Are they an issue? If not match `'+` and replace with `''`

Comment: @SebastianProske that is actually working for me, triple quotes can be ignored in my use case. Can I invite you to put this into an answer - unless there's a duplicate I haven't found?

Comment: Thanks all for answering. I'm accepting Sebastian's answer because it is the simplest in my use case, but I can see the merit in the other answers, especially anubhava's for the cool lookbehind "workaround" and Wiktor's for the powerful callback idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As multiple (=more than 2) quotes are not an issue for you, you don't actually need to take that much care, if there are one or two quotes at a given place, just - so just replace every occurence of quotes with the wanted double quotes. The regex for this would be `/'+/g` and can be replaced by `"''"`

Comment: This is the simplest solution (although maybe not the most universally robust) in my view. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
str = str.replace(/(^|[^'])'(?!')/g, "$1''"));
```

- It matches line start or non single quote character before a single quote and captures it in a group #1.
- Using a negative lookahead it also asserts that matched single quote is not followed by another single quote.
- In replacement we use back-reference of captured group #1 and two `''`

**Full code:**

```js
var arr = ["abc'def", "abc''de'f"];

for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   console.log( arr[i] + ' => ' + arr[i].replace(/(^|[^'])'(?!')/g, "$1''") );
}
```

**Output:**

```
abc'def => ab''def
abc''de'f => abc''d''f
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the workaround for non-supported look-behinds.

Comment: Is there any significant difference between the back-reference notation `$1` and `\1` in Javascript? It seems the latter prints garbled characters when output through `alert` rather than the console.

Comment: Actually I should have used `$1` as `\1` is just there for compatibility purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You may also match 2 or more occurrences of single apostrophes into a capturing group and just match all other single apostrophes, and use a callback to use the right replacement in either cases:

```js
var ss = ["abc'def" , "abc''de'f", "abc''''''def'g"];
for (var s of ss) {
  console.log(s.replace(/('{2,})|'/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $1 : "''"; }));
}
```

This solution won't shrink `'''''`  to `''` as `replace(/'+/g, "''")`  would.

*Details*:

- `('{2,})` - matches and *captures* into Group 1 two or more occurrences of `'`
- `|` - or
- `'` - a single apostrophe is matched in all other contexts.

The callback method accepts `$0` (the whole match) and `$1` (Group 1). If `$1` is not undefined, then its value is reinserted, else `'` (the whole match) is replaced with `''`.

Comment: Looks very interesting too! Maybe a little overkill in my case (should have probably better specified the edge cases, sorry).

Comment: When you need to use different replacements based on what you match, this is the only alternatives (unless the two alternatives are replacing with 1 string or removing the match)

Comment: Yes, I can see this is potentially very powerful.

Comment: Since you come from Java, this is analoguous to `Matcher#appendReplacement()`, but is much easier to use in JS.

Comment: ... with the added anonymization/delegation :)

Answer (score 1):

How about the humble chained replace?

```js
str = "abc'def --> abc''def abc''de'f --> abc''de''f"
console.log(str)
console.log(str.replace(/''/g,"|").replace(/'/g,"''").replace(/\|/g,"''"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems to do the job, but I do not like the multiple chained replacements much.

Comment: I only use it for such simple replacements

Comment: When you can guarantee that your string does not contain your magic char (`|`)

Answer (score 0):

I had success with this regular expression:

```
/([^\'])\'([^\'])/g
```

Example:

```js
var afterRegex = document.getElementsByClassName('after')[0];
var listItems = afterRegex.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {

var string = listItems[i].textContent;
var convertedString = string.replace(/([^\'])\'([^\'])/g, "$1''$2");
listItems[i].textContent = convertedString;

}
```

```css
div {
float: left;
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>Before:</h2>
<ul class="before">
<li>"abc'def"</li>
<li>"abc''de'f"</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<h2>After:</h2>
<ul class="after">
<li>"abc'def"</li>
<li>"abc''de'f"</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Since `[^']` is a *consuming* pattern, the `/([^\'])\'([^\'])/g` regex won't match at the string start/end.

Comment: This will actually consume the character prior to the replaceable single quote, just like `/(?:[^'])'(?!'))/g`.

Comment: If the solution above isn't correct, it's probably safe to assume that I didn't understand the question. ;-)